# How can I have fast communication between server and client in Spring framework?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I'm going to create an client that communicate with a REST API server, powered by Spring framework. In some cases, I want to send data from client -> server and the server should answer back fast as possible, then I'm going to send data from client -> server and the server send data back from server -> client as fast as possible. Repeat it until the user of the client don't send data back any longer.

I think I can do that with a REST API in Spring, but is there any better way? I mean faster way to send data? Or perhaps REST API is fast enough as long I have good communication between server and client?

I'm using Apache HTTPD library to talk with Spring REST API. It works. Here is an example where I connect a REST API with login.

```
        try {
            CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
            credsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(serverAddress.getText(), Integer.parseInt(serverPort.getSelectedItem().getText())), new UsernamePasswordCredentials(userName.getText(), password.getText()));
            CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();
            connections.setHttpclient(httpclient);
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://" + serverAddress.getText() + ":" + serverPort.getSelectedItem().getText() + "/user/connect?username=" + userName.getText());
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            String entity = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            if (entity.equals("connected") == true) {
                connectServerButton.setText("Disconnect from the server");
                dialogs.alertDialog(AlertType.INFORMATION, "Connected", "You are now connected");
                connections.setConnected(true);
                connections.setServerAddress(serverAddress.getText());
                connections.setServerPort(serverPort.getSelectedItem().getText());
                connections.setUserName(userName.getText());
                response.close();
            } else {
                dialogs.alertDialog(AlertType.ERROR, "Not connected", "Failed to login");

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            dialogs.exception("Cannot connect server", e);
        }
```

And the controller is

```
@GetMapping("/connect")
public String connect(@RequestParam("username") String username) {
    // This will connect the user
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    if(user == null)
        return "disconnected";

    // Set some values
    Online online = onlineRepository.findByUsername(username);
    online.setOnline_id(user.getUser_id());
    online.setOnline(false);
    online.setDevice("-");
    onlineRepository.save(online);

    return "connected";
}
```

This is how I do to connect and talk to my REST API. Do you have a better way if I want to have faster communication? I'm not saying that I requrie full-duplex. That would be nice, but not requried. What I requrie is fast response from the server.

Would be happy if the server can response at 10 milliseconds (own LAN network, fast computer, fast DHCP server). I'm not sending large data, only smal strings.

Comment: You could consider websockets or gRPC

Comment: @MartinVanWingerden I cannot do web sockets because the clinent is an Android application.

Comment: GPRC sounds lika a good idea! You think I can combine that with Spring REST API?  :)

Comment: @DanielMårtensson you **can** develop WebSockets for Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send from browser, websocket will be a good solution as you don't need to rebuild the network connection each time.

If you send between backend services, use some RPC or socket communication to keep the connection alive.